# Updating all rows in the table with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am doing a project with Laravel. Database table name / value form, all lines come from the form as name = 'site_url', name = 'site_desc'. How can I update them?

Comment: Did one of the below answers solve your problem? If so, please may you mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your form data from the class `Request`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');
}
```

You can also get all the requests by `Request::all()`

You can read more about requests [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests)

To update a specific table you need to get the table column data into a variable first by doing:

```
$myData = MyModel::where('id', 1)->first();
$myData->site_desc = 'New description';
$myData->save();
```

Comment: My database table is as follows; [screenshot](https://hizliresim.com/drSaS2) . I want to update not by column name, but by line. In addition; is this usage wrong?

Comment: @zekeriyaeroglu if you want to update your data in your table, you need to put the model in a variable. Check santiago Curvello's answer. I'll also update my answer for another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

To update a database record, you will also need the record ID or other field to uniquely identify the record you wish to update.

There are various ways to then execute the update, but here is a simple example, using 'Site' as an example model name:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');    

    $site = Site::findOrFail($id);
    $site->url = $request->input('site_url');
    $site->description = $request->input('site_desc');
    $site->save();
}
```

Note that Laravel automatically escapes the input values for you, so you don't have to do that manually.

Update the model and field names to whatever your application and table use.

Comment: My database table is as follows; [screenshot](https://hizliresim.com/drSaS2) . I want to update not by column name, but by line. In addition; is this usage wrong?

Comment: @zekeriyaeroglu I'm not sure what you mean by 'Update by line'. The example I posted updates one specific line. If you want to update multiple lines at once, you can use `Site::where(...condition...)->update(['name' => $request->input['site_desc'], 'value' => $request->input('site_url')]);` Does that answer your question?

Comment: There will be no where requirement. all rows in the 'value' column of the table will be updated. You can understand better if you look at the screenshot in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

To update a database record you can use:

```
public function update(Request $request, Content $content)
{
    $content->update($request->all());
}
```

In this case Content is the model.